# android. how to end call and back to previous activity

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I tried to make a call, and after I clicked "end call" then back to previous activity (in this case my main menu application). I used phonestatelistener. the problem is when I click end call, it go to my main menu but start to make a call again and again. Is there a solution?

here is my code :

```
public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    String telepon2 = telepon.getText().toString();                 
                    try {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+telepon2));
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                        Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
                    }                   
                }               
            });
```

this is my PhoneStateListener

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
              listener = new ListenToPhoneState();
              tManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

this is my monitor phone call

```
 private class ListenToPhoneState extends PhoneStateListener {

           String LOG_TAG = null;

        @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
                }
                if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                    //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
                }
                if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                    //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    finish();
                }
            }
      }
```

I tried click the button to make call it, then end call it work at once. When I tried to click button call again, it call the number repeatedly.